# How i can show chekboxlist in parent/child relation

Tags: asp.net

How i can show CheckBoxList in parent/child relation. I want to show CheckBoxList of asp.net in parent/child relation.

for example:
                where [] is CheckBox

> - []computer
>
>   []laptop
>     []desktop PC
>     []Monitor
> - []Business
>
>   []Business Ideas
>     []Business
>     Opportunities
>     []Home Business
>     []Industrial
>     []International
>     Business
>     []Management

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can also do it using the TreeView Webcontrol since the TreeNodes in TreeView control support display a checkbox in each node.

Check out the following article

[TreeView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4fz6xk2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to implement this tree using HTML. You can see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/saranghdave/F7BDu/).

Please correct me if I am wrong.